# Loop within try catch where exception is thrown in condition of do while loop in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to complete loop ignoring the exception.please suggest?

```
try {
do{
        driver.navigate().refresh();

                }while(!driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Completed")).isDisplayed());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }
}
```

Comment: Put the `try/catch` inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Put the try-catch inside the loop and use a variable to hold the result of the evaluation that you do in the condition :

```
boolean cont = false;
do {
    try {
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        cont = !driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Completed")).isDisplayed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        cont = true; // if you want the loop to continue after an exception
                     // or false if you want to terminate the loop in this case
    }
} while (cont);
```